# Free Shipping for magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm very new to the Magento 2 framework. I would like to know that how to set up free shipping above the amount 50 dollars and below amount should have 6.5 dollar shipping charges.
Please help me to solve this problem.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-set-up-free-shipping-rules-in-magento-2/ It will help you.